# haskell sorting list of custom datatypes based on common atributes without usingf modules

Tags: sorting, haskell, pattern-matching, custom-data-attribute, algebraic-data-types

Im trying to order a list of a custom datatype with different size of atributes to validate if the datatype format is true but I don't know how to manipulate it by using quick sort.

The datatype:

```
data Cuidado = Comprar String Int | Medicar String
```

I'm testing pattern matching with quicksort but it doesnt make any sense.

```
valCui :: [Cuidado] -> [Cuidado]
valCui [] = []
valCui (x:xs) = valCui [a | a <- xs, x > a] ++ [x] ++ valCui [a | a <- xs, x <= a]
```

Output is supposed to be:

```
valCui [Medicar med7, Comprar med4 30] == [Comprar med4 30, Medicar med7]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are only two small problems here:

1. You have a `->` operator in your list comprehension. Presumably you mean to check the greater-than relation here, but the operator for that is just `>`. The `->` arrow is special syntax, reserved for function signatures, lambdas and `case` assignments.
2. In order to be able to use such comparison operators on your custom data type, you need it to have an instance of the [`Ord`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Ord) typeclass. But yours doesn't, or at least you didn't show it. The easiest way to get such an instance is to derive it:

   ```
   data Cuidado = Comprar String Int | Medicar String
    deriving (Eq, Ord)
   ```

Comment: I edited the -> operator. I mistyped it. 

I added the typeclasses now. 
But how does the pattern matching work in quick sorting on this occasion?

Comment: Well, the `(x:xs)` pattern splits up the input list into: one arbitrary element `x` (in this version, the first element, though in real applications it's actually preferred to select a random element instead), and all the rest of the list `xs`. Then the two list comprehensions partition `xs` into all elements that are less- and all that are greater than `x`, respectively.

Comment: But lets say I wanted to sort it based on the string attribute of cuidado and medicar. How to i pattern match it?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Also, it seems to be a rather different question from the one you asked originally, so perhaps you should post it as a new question.